# controller method never called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in AngularJS, I want to call signup method on button `ng-click`, but it never gets called.

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-5" style="" ng-controller="SignUpController">
    <div class="row">
        <button  ng-click="$parent.signup()" class="form-control btn btn-primary">Sign-Up</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular Script

```
<script>

    angular.module('index',[])
    .controller('SignUpController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

      $scope.signup=function(){
        alert("");
      };

    }]);

</script>
```

Comment: Why did you use `$parent` scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <button  ng-click="signup()" class="form-control btn btn-primary">Sign-Up</button>
```

in your case $parent does not have method signup